# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_1^a \frac{n}{1+x^n} \, dx$

Tags: integration, limits

I'm trying to find $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}   \int_1^a \dfrac{n}{1+x^n} \, dx  ,$$ where parameter $a>1$.

The limit appears to be $\ln 2$ regardless of the value of $a$.

Some trick is probably needed here, but i don't see it.

Comment: Do you know contour integration?

Comment: Not really. But i will take a look!

Comment: It looks like the limit is $\log 2$, regardless of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Put $$x=tan^{2/n}\theta$$
          $$ dx=\dfrac2ntan^{\frac2n-1}\theta \times sec^2\theta . d\theta$$

> Now =>   $$\boxed{I_n=\int_\phi^\psi 2tan^{\frac2n-1}\theta . d\theta}$$
>   $\phi,\psi$ are the limits accordingly.
>   $$\phi=tan^{-1}1=\pi/4$$
>   and $$\psi=tan^{-1}[a^\frac n2]$$
>   $$Lt_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ \ \ [\psi]=\pi/2$$
>
> $$Lt_{n\rightarrow\infty}[I_n]=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{2cos\theta}{sin\theta}.d\theta$$.

#### So,it can be done!

Answer (score 12):

$$\begin{align*}\int_1^a \frac{n}{1+x^n}\,dx &=\int_{1}^a\frac{n}{x^n}\left(\frac{1 }{1+(1/x)^n}\right)dx\\&=\int_1^a\frac{n}{x^n}\left(1-\frac{1}{x^n}+\frac{1}{x^{2n}}-\cdots\right)dx\\&=n\int_1^a\frac{1}{x^n}-\frac{1}{x^{2n}}+\frac{1}{x^{3n}}-\cdots\,dx\\&=n\left[\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{2n-1}+\cdots\right]-\underbrace{n\left[\frac{a^{1-n}}{n-1}-\frac{a^{1-2n}}{2n-1}+\cdots\right]}_{\to\,0}\end{align*}$$

$$\text{Since}\; \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{kn-1}=\frac{1}{k}:$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^a \frac{n}{1+x^n}dx=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\cdots =\ln 2$$

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT**: I tried to make my answer more rigorous.

Let $u = x^{n}$.

Then we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_1^a \frac{n}{1+x^n} \, \mathrm  dx =\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^{a^{n}} \frac{u^{1/n-1}}{1+u}  \, \mathrm  du = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} \boldsymbol{1}_{[1,a^{n}]}(u) \,   \frac{u^{1/n-1}}{1+u}  \, \mathrm  du.$$

For $n \ge 2$, the integrand is dominated by the integrable function $\frac{u^{-1/2}}{1+u}$.

So by appealing to the the dominated convergence theorem, we can conclude that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_1^a \frac{n}{1+x^n} \, \mathrm  dx = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{u^{-1}}{1+u} \, \mathrm  du   = \int_{1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{1+u} \right) \mathrm du = \ln 2.$$