# Finding the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_1^a \frac{n}{1+x^n} dx$ with $a > 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> $I_n$ is given by $$I_n=\int_1^a \dfrac{n \ dx}{1+x^n}, \qquad a>1.$$
>   Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}I_n$.

Comment: And see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339685/lim-n-to-infty-displaystyle-int-1a-dfracn1xndx

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Put $$x=tan^{2/n}\theta$$
          $$ dx=\dfrac2ntan^{\frac2n-1}\theta \times sec^2\theta . d\theta$$

> Now =>   $$\boxed{I_n=\int_\phi^\psi 2tan^{\frac2n-1}\theta . d\theta}$$
>   $\phi,\psi$ are the limits accordingly.
>   $$\phi=tan^{-1}1=\pi/4$$
>   and $$\psi=tan^{-1}[a^\frac n2]$$
>   $$Lt_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ \ \ [\psi]=\pi/2$$
>
> $$Lt_{n\rightarrow\infty}[I_n]=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{2cos\theta}{sin\theta}.d\theta$$.

#### So,it can be done!

Comment: But the limits are also dependent on $n$.

Comment: @IvanLoh  Yes , $\phi=\pi/4$ and $\psi=arctan(a^{\frac n2})$ and at $n\rightarrow\infty : \psi=\pi/2$. I'll show this in solution too.