# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_1^a \frac{n}{1+x^n}dx$ solution with term-by-term integration of series

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Term-by-term integration was given as one of the solutions:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339717/851293

From the theory, the power series can be integrated term-by-term on an interval lying inside the interval of convergence, but how to prove this solution is allowed for this particular case since the function also depends on $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be shown that:
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^n}dx$$
converges for all $n>1$ so the integral part will converge. One nice way you could do it would be:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^n}<\frac 1{x^n}\,\,\,\,x\ge1$$
so:
$$\int_1^a\frac{n}{1+x^n}dx<\int_1^a\frac{n}{x^n}dx=\frac{(a^n-a)n}{a^n(n-1)}=a\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{a^{n-1}-1}{a^n}=\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{a^{n-1}-1}{a^{n-1}}=\frac{n}{n-1}\left(1-a^{1-n}\right)=L_n$$
which when we look at very large values of $n$ it is clear that:
$$\frac{n}{n-1}\to1$$
$$1-a^{1-n}\to1$$
also since the function is always positive and $a>1$ then the integral must also be positive, and so:
$$0\le I<1$$